# how to iterate arrays in angular 12? (typescript firebase)

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, firebase, ngfor

I am learning typescritp and I have already been around the web a thousand times and I did not find anything clear about how to iterate arrays
with ngfor to display on screen ...
below an image of how I am saving the data in firestore.
I would like to show each array eg "title", "date" like the image below (with documents without arrays there is no problem)

[datos firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwHLH.jpg)

my service:

```
listarNotificacionSrv3(): Observable<any> {
return this.firestore.collection('notificacion').get();}
```

my component

```
listarNotificacion2() {
this.subscription = this.notificacionService
  .listarNotificacionSrv3()
  .subscribe((doc) => {
    console.log('doc', doc);
    this.listarnotificacion2 = [];
    doc.forEach((element: any) => {
      this.listarnotificacion2.push({
        id: element.payload.doc.id,
        ...element.payload.doc.data(),
      });
    });
  });}
```

my html:(Here I don't know how to iterate the arrays in my particular case)

```
<div class="card mt-3" *ngFor="let datos of listarnotificacion2 | keyvalue ">
 <h5>ver: {{datos}}</h5>
</div>
```

the expected jajaja:
[view data in screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXafj.png)

returns on screen with snaphshotChanges ()
[returns on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xneJm.jpg)

From already thank you very much!
cheers!

sorry for my inglish...

Comment: You're iterating correctly. You're using *ngFor the right way already. Can you please add a screenshot of what is currently rendered by your HTML now ?

Comment: Can you add a result of the console.log('doc', doc); ?

Comment: hi, with snapshotChanges () in service I get the image that I add.